# Don't want to leave freelancing

Tags: freelance-websites

I am not getting customers who pay well for Mobile App Development.  All the customers I meet either don't have money or they do not like to spend much money.  I am a freelancer in India, and Indian customers do not want to spend anything; still they want best service.  What can I do in this situation?  I don't want to leave freelancing but I am finding it difficult to survive.

Comment: Look outside of India.

Comment: Are you really so good or you think you are good? I have seen many good guys who prove to be just juniors when I started checking their projects. This means improve your skills. Other point is set your price and stick to it. Bid to 1 project in a day or more days, but analyze it in details. If a client see your expertise in the bid, he will pay you more than he would pay another person. You will not get $100/h, but you will get enough to make a good living in India.

Comment: Here in this question I am focusing on the customers who are looser, don't have money to spend but still think they can make good app or website. Hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have the technical skills that are in demand, have you asked yourself why you might not be getting the work?

Are you chasing mom/pop type business who don't have the skill/knowledge to communicate effectively with what they want? Perhaps your ability to understand or even ask the customer is not strong (don't be offended - we all have our strengths, and often, we fail to acknowledge or weaknesses).

Consulting/freelancing/contracting... whatever you want to call it is not easy - its can be profitable, highly profitable, but its not easy. You have to have technical skill, marketing ability, accountability (both from a financial management sense, project management and communication sense). Few manage to perfect all of these.

I'm not trying to scare you away but by posing these thoughts and giving honest consideration it might help you find what part of your strategy is letting you down.

The customers you approach might be less familiar with getting others in another timezone, or even another continent to deliver a project. It depends heavily on communication - I've been contracting/consulting since 1994 and most of the rich work is available when the customer can see you if not daily, at least at some frequency. Projects change, costs change, timelines change - having to communicate this puts up front risk on the customer.

Then there are liability risks - despite your best and most honest efforts, if your code results in the customer being held liable, the customer will have to pursue you thru expensive international courts if they are to hold you liable.

Some customers might think the risk/reward is just too much. Lean towards thinking of benefits the customer will win, then figure out how you can profit from making your customer win.

Example... A friend of mine was one of three founders at a Brazilian viral-ad making company. Their initial attempts to win customers proved unworkable so their alternative approach was to create products and sell the ideas to marketing companies who in turn would sell the ideas on to their customers. It made them a small fortune which included a couple of awards at Cannes film festival (which I believe, includes awards for adverts).

Thus - perhaps you might want to consider creating products that are easily customizable with templates that target a specific market like real estate, car buying or health/sports/wellness. Select ten clients from somewhere in the world, copy/paste their branding from their website into your solution and contact them to try your product out. Cost accordingly - don't be shy - if you are too cheap, they won't look and if they are too expensive, they won't search either (do your own research for the market and region you are targeting). Don't sell the code, but sell the solution (thus allowing you to re-use the code with someone else's branding).

You might get one in ten who say yes - and failing that, you'll have learned other skills in the process.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

Spend a bit of time and work on your onboarding process.

When a client comes to you for a mobile app, they are already in a state of mind that they will be spending money. They just need to know how much money.

With your onboarding, make the client feel comfortable that you are able to bring their ideas to life. Explain in detail how you will approach the project and how you will add value to their idea.

Clients are more likely to say yes if they understand exactly what value they will be getting for their money.

Sure, in the end, they will get a mobile app, but it will be an app that brings value to their company, personal life, or other people.